# give the alias name dynamically same as declare variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
declare @counter int =1

create table #temp (name varchar(100), value varchar(100))
insert into #temp values ('test','100')
insert into #temp values ('test','100')
```

just want to change the column name `value` as `value+@counter`, it should be dynamic in while loop query, 
can you please give me suggestion to make the column name while looping through sql server..

Answer (score 0):

You seems want recursive cte :

```
with r_cte as (
     select 'test' as name, 100 as val
     union all
     select name, val + @counter
     from r_cte
     where val < ? -- define length
)
insert into #temp (name, value)
   select rc.name, rc.val
   from r_cte rc;
```